# Sequence contains No elements when getting Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

ExtraTime in here represents extra time in Basketball. Since most matches don't have extra time, ExtraTime will be null many times.

I've searched other questions and wrote this and it worked. The code checks if is there any extra time, if not make it 0. And do not include 0's when calculating average.

```
OverTime = Math.Round(dtos.Select(p => (decimal)(p.ExtraTimeHomeTeamScore ?? 0)).Where(p => p != 0).Average(), 2),
```

Then i tried to do something  more complex. This one to check two different data types and calculate average of them. Also don't include 0's. For some reason it returns Sequence Error.

```
 OverTime = Math.Round((decimal)(dtos.Where(p => p.DataType == 0).Select(p => p.ExtraTimeHomeTeamScore ?? 0).Where( p => p != 0).Average()
                        + dtos.Where(p => p.DataType == 1).Select(p => p.ExtraTimeAwayTeamScore ?? 0).Where(p => p != 0).Average()) / 2, 2)
```

I tried to write just like first code. Whatever i do, i couldn't get rid of **Sequence Contains No Element** Error. What part of my code is wrong, and can be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you can't `Average` nothing

However you can use [`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns the elements of an `IEnumerable<T>`, or a default valued
>   singleton collection if the sequence is empty.

```
var result = dtos.Where(p => p.DataType == 0)
                 .Select(p => p.ExtraTimeHomeTeamScore ?? 0)
                 .Where( p => p != 0)
                 .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                 .Average();
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. I don't need to include 0 inside DeaultIfEmpty i guess, it returns zero value without it.

Comment: @BatuhanAydın indeed it does when dealing with numeric types

Answer (score 1):

Check the [IEnumerable.Average](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=netframework-4.8) documentation:

> **Exceptions**
>
> ArgumentNullException
>
> source is null.
>
> **InvalidOperationException**
>
> source contains no elements.

Your problem is when your filters (where clauses) return nothing. So when the resulting enumerables contain not elements, what would be the average value of them?

I would do something like this:

```
var filteredDtos1 = dtos.Where(p => p.DataType == 0).Select(p => p.ExtraTimeHomeTeamScore ?? 0).Where( p => p != 0);
var filteredDtos2 = dtos.Where(p => p.DataType == 1).Select(p => p.ExtraTimeAwayTeamScore ?? 0).Where(p => p != 0).Average();

var avg1 = filteredDtos1.Count > 0 : filteredDtos1.Average ? //some default value probably 0;
var avg2 = filteredDtos2.Count > 0 : filteredDtos2.Average ? //some default value probably 0;

OverTime = Math.Round((decimal)(avg1 + avg2) / 2, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I included DefaultIfEmpty() before calculating average and it solved the problem.Also thank you for the code change suggestion.